# Find index in multidimensionnal array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wish to find the postion (id) of a value in multidimensionnal array.

```js
var arr = [
  ['France', 'FA', 'Paris'],
  ['Allemagne', 'AJ', 'Berlin']
];

var x = 'France';

var index = arr.findIndex(id => id === x);

console.log(index);
```

Expected : 0, Got: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `id` is an array you can't directly compare it to a string. Instead use something like [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var arr = [
  ['France', 'FA', 'Paris'],
  ['Allemagne', 'AJ', 'Berlin']
];

var x = 'France';

var index = arr.findIndex(subarr => subarr.includes(x));

console.log(index);
```

If you still want a compare function you can also try out [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), this is more useful if you need to check something like an object property.

```js
var arr = [
  ['France', 'FA', 'Paris'],
  ['Allemagne', 'AJ', 'Berlin']
];

var x = 'France';

var index = arr.findIndex(subarr => subarr.some(id => id === x));

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a custom search function for multi-dimensional arrays

Like the following

```js
var arr = [
 
   ['France','FA','Paris']
  ,['Allemagne', 'AJ', 'Berlin'] 

];
var x = 'AJ';


function get2DIndex(arr, query){
  let iter = 0;
  for(let i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
  
    for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
      if(query === arr[i][j]) return iter;
      
      iter++;
    
    }
  }
  

}

var index = get2DIndex(arr, x)

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce` to find every occurrence of the string you are searching for. the results are [[`row`,`column`],....]

```js
var arr = [
  ['France', 'FA', 'Paris'],
  ['Allemagne', 'AJ', 'Berlin']
];

var x = 'France';

let result = arr.reduce((acc,e,i) => {
    let index = e.indexOf(x)
    if(index > -1)
        acc.push([i,index])
    return acc
},[])

console.log(result)
```